# Are answers relying on biased first-person supplied subjective information valid?

Tags: discussion, answers, citations

For a claim in the form of:

> Is the *(potentially negative)* fact F about a person P true?

Is the following answer's **conclusion** considered valid? (and if not, **what would be the conclusion that is legitimately supported by supplied level of evidence?**)

> According to an interview with person P themselves, they have stated that the fact F is false

Specific properties of the answer that I'd like to highlight are:

1. This first person response from person P is the only evidence cited
2. Person P has a plausible motivation respond with "false" no matter what the actual truth is (e.g. if it were true, they would look worse off to other people).

   <sub>As @Sklivvz noted, this can be somewhat subjective, but not always (in other words, a reasonable person can be reliably assumed to be motivated to NOT want to admit to being a criminal, or to have failed in some endeavour/life using a well established criteria). Basically, the point here is to establish that there may be a plausible reason for the person to NOT tell the truth in the interview, in which case the onus is on the answerer to prove the facts to be as stated.</sub>
3. Fact "F" in the first-person response is subjectively defined (as an example, the interview asks if a person is "successful", or "wealthy/poor", etc... without any definition of what that means).

Comment: See my [other comment](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/are-answers-about-efficacy-based-on-logic-instead-of-efficacy-testing-valid#comment8198_2926): "Is it valid?" is the wrong question to ask. "What can be deducted?" is a much better question. Also note that point 2 is not an objectively measurable attribute. It's up to the reader to infer.

Comment: @Sklivvz - In the specific example I had in mind, #2 was pretty unambiguous, but you are correct that it may be subjective in a generic case. I will add the clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are statements by a biased person in reference to situation related to themselves considered sufficient standard of proof?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/are-statements-by-a-biased-person-in-reference-to-situation-related-to-themselve)

Comment: @Sklivvz -  you made a valid point in your first comment. The spirit of my question is more about how definitive of a conclusion can be deducted from such evidence.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly a valid form of evidence, but not all forms of evidence are appropriate in all contexts. We need to be careful about what conclusions we draw, but -- assuming the evidence is true, i.e. they actually said what is attributed to them -- it is *valid evidence*.

What can be inferred by it is contextual.

For example:

- A valid conclusion: "Is the Pope a self-described atheist?" "No: the Pope said in an interview that he's Catholic"
- An invalid conclusion: "Did OJ Simpson kill his wife?" "No: he denied it in an interview"

More in general, it's very very unlikely that one can sustain an *absolute* conclusion from hearsay. Bias is simply one of the factors of why this is so, but there's many more reasons.